# For loop across multiple columns

Tags: r

I have some data from a questionnaire that measures frequency of entering a shop ("_freq") and enjoyment of the experience ("_enj"). Overall, there are 17 shops (shop1, shop2, ...) and 120 rows of data. Below is an example of 5 rows of data for just shop 1 and 2.

| shop1_freq | shop1_enj | shop2_freq | shop2_enj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9 | 5 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 9 |
| 0 | 9 | 5 | 4 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 | 9 |
| 4 | 9 | 5 | 4 |

I have written a for loop that labels incorrect responses to the questionnaire as "999" so that I can identify them. Basically, for each shop in isolation, a response is incorrect if frequency is 0 and enjoyment is **not** 9, or the reverse, if frequency is **not** 0 but enjoyment is 9. At the moment I am repeating the loops below 17 times (individually for each shop, below is just shop 1).

```
for (rows in 1:120){  
  if(data$shop1_freq[rows] == "0" & data$shop1_enj[rows] != 9) { 
    data$shop1_enj[rows] = "999" # label incorrect 999
  }
}

for (rows in 1:120){  
  if(data$shop1_freq[rows] != "0" & data$shop1_enj[rows] == 9) { 
    data$shop1_enj[rows] = "999" # label incorrect 999
  }
}
```

However I wondered if there was a more efficient way to do this for all 17 shops in less code?

Comment: Yes.  Use [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) data.  Your life will be simpler, your code will be more compact, more robust and more readable.  Here, a tidy data format would have columns for `Row`/`ID`, `Shop`, `Freq` and `Enjoyment`.  You could then write, say, `df <- df %>% mutate(Freq=ifelse(Freq == 0 & Enjoyment != 9, 999, Freq), Enjoyment=ifelse(Enjoyment == 0 & Freq != 9, 999, Enjoyment))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with `across` in `mutate` for multiple 'shop_\d+_enj' columns and its corresponding '_freq' columns

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- data %>%
    mutate(across(matches('^shop\\d+_enj$'), ~ {
             tmp <- get(str_replace(cur_column(), '_enj', '_freq'))
             case_when(tmp == 0 &  . != 9 ~ 999, 
                       tmp != 0 & . == 9 ~ 999,
                    TRUE ~ .)

      }))
```

Details -

We loop `across` the columns that match 'shop' followed by one or more digits, then a `_` and the 'enj' in column names, `get` the corresponding column of 'freq', by replacing the column name (`cur_column()`) suffix '_enj' with '_freq', use that to create the compound conditional expression with logical operators in `case_when`, if the value is TRUE, then assign (`~`) those row elements to 999, and the default values are returned in the last `TRUE ~ .`.  Here, `.` is the column values

---

In `base R`, this can be done with multiple ways.  One option is to split the data into a `list` based on the pattern of column names

```
lst1 <- split(data1, sub("_.*", "", names(data1))
out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(lst1, function(x) {
       x[[2]] <- ifelse(x[[1]] == 0 & x[[2]] != 9, 999,
     ifelse(x[[1]] != 0 & x[[2]] == 9, 999, x[[2]])))
     x 
     }))
```

Comment: the dplyr option works by changing incorrect responses to "999" under the frequency columns (_freq). Is it possible to further amend that code so that it subsets the data by removing any column which contains 999? (i.e., an incorrect response)

Comment: @abc_95 can you post as a new question to understand it better